# How do I only allow a command to be toggled by users with certain permissions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, discord, discord.js

I have coded a bot that can format text - I need it so that not just randoms can access the command. Here is my code - it throws no errors

```js
try {
    if(message.member.guild.me.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      if (args[0] === 'off') {
        christian[message.guild.id] = false
      } else if (args[0] === 'on') {
        christian[message.guild.id] = true
      }
      message.channel.send(`Christian Mode ${christian[message.guild.id] ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}`)
      return christian
    } else {
      message.channel.send('You do not have permission to use that command!')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Permission Error')
  }
```

note: the command is toggled back to the index.js (main) by saying =Christian on/off this function works.

Comment: Doesn't ```hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')``` do the required?!

Comment: @mas That line checks that the *bot's* permissions, not the command executor's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.member.guild.me.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')` is checking the *bot's* permissions, not the command executor's. Call [`GuildMember#hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) on `message.member` (see [`Message#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member)).

For example...

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
  // return an error to the user (and actually return)
}

// continue with command code
```

---

<sub>**NOTE:** The Discord.js documentation hyperlinked is for recently released v12. If your Discord.js isn't up to date, switch to the correct version at the top of the page for accurate info.</sub>

Comment: If I wanted to add another perm would I make it
`if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR' || 'MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {`
?

Comment: @Proto You could pass an array of strings to `GuildMember#hasPermission`, like so: `message.member.hasPermission(['ADMINISTRATOR', 'MANAGE_MESSAGES'])`. If you were to use the OR operator (`||`), you'd have to call it twice; the method doesn't read it.

Comment: Ah okay, I’ll implement this, thank you for the help, it is much appreciated